# Getting the updated XML element based on variable values in VB.Net

Tags: xml, vb.net

So, I have a simple code to get the value of connection string from XML.

```
        connectionString = root.<TestDB>.Value.ToString
```

As you can see, "TestDB" is the element name that gives me connection name. I want to replace this "TestDB" with a variable. Sadly, I am unable to figure out how to do that.

Below is the XML I am using.

```
<connections>
  <TestDB>Data Source=GAMING;Initial Catalog=BasicDB;User ID=sa;Password=J1tendr@</TestDB>
  <TestDBConnectionType>SQL</TestDBConnectionType>
  <NewDB>ConnectionType=SQL;Data Source=GAMING;Initial Catalog=BasicDB;User ID=sa;Password=J1tendr@</NewDB>
  <NewDBConnectionType>SQL</NewDBConnectionType>
</connections>
```

I want to get the connection string based on which connection name programmer uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use [`.Element()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to find first child having element name equals certain name, for example :

```
Dim elementName As String = "TestDB"
connectionString = root.Element(elementName).Value
```

<kbd>[`Dotnetfiddle Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2TLDVI)</kbd>

Comment: Let me quickly try that. Sounds promising.

Edit: Apparently there is no such property named Element. Elements is the one though, and that works wonderfully.

Comment: @jitendragarg really, there is no `Element()`? That would be surprising, I've been using that method many times. Of what type is your `root` variable?

Comment: It is `XML.Linq.XElement` type

Comment: @jitendragarg Both `Element()` and `Elements()` should've existed. See demo for `Element()` method usage : https://dotnetfiddle.net/2TLDVI

Comment: I don't know why it wasn't there. Anyway, Elements worked. So, I am fine with it.